# HttpClient implementation in .NET Standard 2 library which is referenced in Droid project

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, .net-standard-2.0

I have an instance of HttpClient in a .NET Standard 2 library and the Droid project references the library. In the Droid project HttpClient implementation is set to Android. Will the HttpClient implementation use java.net.URLConnection or the HttpClientHandler?

[image: Android Options]

I want it to use the native HttpClient. In case it uses the managed HttpClientHandler, do I need to add a special case for Android in my shared code library like this:

```
// if we're on any other platform
HttpClient client = new HttpClient()
// if we're on Android    
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler ())
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/http-stack?tabs=windows

Answer (score 0):

If you specify in the project options the type of client, you just need to initialize the HttpClient(), without specifying it's type.

From the docs:

```
// This will use the default message handler for the application; as
// set in the Project Options for the project.
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

// This will create an HttpClient that explicitly uses the CFNetworkHandler
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new CFNetworkHandler());

// This will create an HttpClient that explicitly uses NSUrlSessionHandler
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new NSUrlSessionHandler());
```